# I have a problem with the for loop Python

Tags: python, arrays, for-loop, insert, target

I have a problem when using the for loop, I don't know why my loop is not working as expected.

CODE:

```
class Solution:
    def searchInsert(nums, target):
        pos = 0
        for i in nums:
            if nums[pos] != target:
                pos = pos + 1
                
            print(pos)
            break

Solution.searchInsert([1,3,5,6], 5)
```

This program receives an array of integers and another integer which I call target, the script has to give me back the position in the array in which we have the number of the target.

In this case my array "nums" contains [1,3,5,6] and my target is 5, so the result must be 2, because the number of the target (5) is in the position "2" of the array.

The problem comes when I run the script. Instead of a 2 the script gives me a 1

If someone catches the error in the code please tell me.

Comment: Why not just use `nums.index(target)`?

Comment: You're instancing the iterator outside of the loop and incrementing it outside of the control structure.  That's curious. Try tracing your values with this statement after you declare your for loop:

   print("i is %i, pos is %i, target is %i" %(i,pos, target))

Comment: You seem to be breaking the loop after the first iteration (but the indentation in your post is weird). That's why you get 1, which is the first update of `pos`.

Comment: Your function will always implicitly return None because you explicitly *break* the *for* loop during its first iteration. You might also want to re-read the Leetcode instructions for this function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are closing the loop after the first iteration: you need to add an `else:` block so it can keep going **until** the condition is met...

```
class Solution:
    def searchInsert(nums, target):
        pos = 0
        for i in nums:
            if nums[pos] != target:
                pos = pos + 1
            else:    
                print(pos)
                break
```

```
>>> Solution.searchInsert([1,3,5,6],5)
2
```

Comment: makes sense, I don't know how I didn't realize that. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

you could use enumerate which gives you the index and value

```
class Solution:
    def searchInsert(nums, target):
        for index, value in enumerate(nums):
            if value == target:
                return index 
             
print(Solution.searchInsert([1,3,5,6], 5))
```

Answer (score 1):

I am posting here just fixed code but as others pointed out, its a strange way to deal with it. But I understand, if you learn Python and come from other language (Visual Basic?), one would go this way.
In python indent is crucial. In your code, you need to increase pos everytime code goes through cycle, not only when you find/did not find the value you want.

```
class Solution:
    def searchInsert(nums, target):
        pos = 0
        for i in nums:
            if nums[pos] == target:
                print(pos) #replace with return pos ?
                break
            pos = pos + 1 #increase outside above condition

Solution.searchInsert([1,3,5,6], 5)
```

To make this code easier, one liner, investigate other users comments. Or research array index, length and later pandas module.

Comment: Don't fforget to upvote answers or mark as answered.

Comment: i cant upvote because i need 15 reputation :(

Comment: i cant mark more than one answer as accepted, thats why I commented you that your answer is also valid and works well